# Splitting a string with a range in python

Tags: python, split

I have a file which contains something similar to the following lines:

```
[<data_type0>,<data_type1>] name(data)
"DATA_VALUE0"|"DATA_VALUE1" name(data)
```

I am looking to split each line into two. The first part being between either the '<' and '>' the '[' and ']' or  " and ".

So the output from the desired split would be something like:

```
valueA[0] = [data_type0,data_type1]
valueA[1] = [name(data)]

valueB[0] = [DATA_VALUE0,DATA_VALUE1]
valueB[1] = [name(data)]
```

One snag is that the data values are of an unknown length, so some lines could read:

```
<date_type0> name(data)
```

and others could be:

```
<data_type0>,<data_type1>,<data_type2>...<data_type8> name(data)
```

Any ideas how?

Comment: It is very hard to help you if you don't show us enough *real* data.

Comment: That is the 'real' data. I've just replaced the 'real' words with 'data_type' and 'name'

Comment: RE: "Have you tried any coding ?" How is that comment helpful? What is the point of typing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

#### Code:

```
lines = (
    '"[ < data_type0 >, < data_type1 >] name(data)',
    '"DATA_VALUE0" | "DATA_VALUE1" name(data)',
)

for line in lines:
    print(line.rsplit(' ', 1))
```

#### Results:

```
['"[ < data_type0 >, < data_type1 >]', 'name(data)']
['"DATA_VALUE0" | "DATA_VALUE1"', 'name(data)']
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could just split on a space .

```
>>> data = """[<data_type0>,<data_type1>] name(data)
... "DATA_VALUE0"|"DATA_VALUE1" name(data)"""
>>> for line in data.split("\n"):
...     print(line.split())
... 
['[<data_type0>,<data_type1>]', 'name(data)']
['"DATA_VALUE0"|"DATA_VALUE1"', 'name(data)']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a general approach to finding stuff in strings and breaking them apart.

```
a = '<data_1>,<data_2> name(data)'
division = a.find('name(')
b = a[:division-1]
c = a[division:]
```

Results:

```
>>> b
'<data_1>,<data_2>'
>>> c
'name(data)'
```